# How to hide blank labels on bars in TeeChart

Tags: teechart

I have a bar graph where each bar represents a value for a specific date.  Since the data does not occur equally spaced in time, I am using an incrementing integer for the X value, and putting the date in as the label value.  Some bars do not have a date (the label is empty). The graph shows empty label values as label boxes containing "0", rather than hiding the label boxes for those bars entirely (which would make sense, since the labels are empty, not "0").  Is there any way to instruct TeeChart to remove those unnecessary and confusing label boxes?

Comment: Could you please retag your question with the language you use TeeChart with? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like this is the same question asked at Steema Software forums: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13901&p=61004#p61004